# Symfony 3 - Form validation error fields not displaying

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, symfony, twig

I've been looking for answer for this simple question but I can't find a working solution. There are only two fields and my main purpose is just to display the validation errors by the respective fields.

My Entity Class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample")
 */
class Sample
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $first_name
     */
    public function setFirstName($first_name)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $last_name
     */
    public function setLastName($last_name)
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
    }


}
```

My Form Class:

```
class Sampleform extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName')
                ->add('lastName');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Sample::class]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_sampleform';
    }
}
```

My Controller Function:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(Sampleform::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            return new Response("Same");
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
```

I am lost in the twig view since when I try the code below it shows the errors while the other twig view doesn't render the error messages even though the debug toolbar detects the error.

My Twig View (3-lines form render):

```
{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button class="btn btn-info" >Save</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

My Twig View (individual fields):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{ form_label(form.lastName) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.lastName) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}

        {{ form_label(form.lastName) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.lastName) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}

        <button class="btn btn-info" >Save</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Bootstrap version is 4 BETA 2
Twig form themes already configured

Comment: In the second template, you have template tags for form.lastName twice, and errors for form.firstName are not output. And because of that, form.firstName will also never be sent

Comment: I think it is still the same. I just forgot to replaced the lastName to firstName on the first field.  Anyways I'll try what you've suggested when I got home.

Comment: Just an update @martinczerwi, I just tried it but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. The issue is on my bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes

As far as I see you should call validation from specific service or to add constraints in form class. For example:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
    ])
            ->add('lastName');
}
```